# GCP & Wordpress: Domain redirecting to external ip instead

Tags: multisite, wp-redirect, domain-mapping

I have purchased domain in Godaddy and hosting in Google Cloud Platform with external ip of 34.106.155.119. It is a wordpress VM instance.

I tried to point the domain name to external ip by changing A and Cname in GCP & updating name servers in Godaddy.

But when I type the domain name in url, it redirects to the ip where wordpress is installed with domain name as 'new' after url. http://34.106.155.119.nip.io/wp-signup.php?new=www.abc.com

Below are the cloud zone settings. Wondering what's wrong here that instead of pointing to same, it is redirecting to ip

abc.com. A 300 Default 34.106.155.119 abc.com.
SOA 21600 Default ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300
abc.com. NS 21600 Default ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com. ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com. ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com. ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com.
[www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com). CNAME 300 Default abc.com

Greatly appreciate help on this